# Discord.js / Node.js FS - Reload a file in same session?

Tags: node.js, discord.js, fs

For better context, i'm setting up a lottery system and after it picks a winner it resets the json file to "{}". While in the same discord session, it still reads the previous file state and not the updated one.

```
var lottery = []
...
function reset(){
    fs.writeFile("./tickets.json", "{}", (err) => {
        if (err) console.log(err)
})
lottery = [];
}
```

Once re-reading tickets.json, it's still it's previous state. If you can do a normal fix for this instead of reading another array instead of a json that would be such a headache relief.

Comment: Is your json edited or not? You can try to delete require cache.

Answer (score 0):

try setting an interval to reload the command?